# How can I select the fields in the query with MongoDB Geospatial?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, geospatial

I'm using MongoDB Geospatial with node.js and express for query the nearest streets near a specific point.
In my result I want to select only the fields of 'name' and 'address'.
I've tried this code below but it doesn't work and I'm getting this error:

"Unhandled rejection Error: Can't use $select with Array."

Thanks.

```
Street.find({
    'location': {
        $near: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: coords
            },
            $maxDistance: 1000
        },
        $select: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 1,
            address: 1
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found it:

```
Street.find(
    {
        'location': {
            $near: {
                $geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: coords},
                $maxDistance: 1000
            }
        }
    })
    .select({'_id': 0, 'name': 1, 'address': 1})
```